# Image Capture in BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, swing, awt, bufferedimage

I am new here and also quite new to Java.
I am making an app where one can select an area of image and it simply returns the selected coordinates. The problem is that, instead of displaying the image, it displays a black area instead of the image.
Also tried with BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB and now it shows a blank area.

Here is the code. Please help.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ScreenCaptureRectangle {

Rectangle captureRect;

ScreenCaptureRectangle(final Image im) {
    final BufferedImage screenCopy = new BufferedImage(
            im.getWidth(null),
            im.getHeight(null),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    final BufferedImage screenCopy1 = new BufferedImage(
            im.getWidth(null),
            im.getHeight(null),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    final JLabel screenLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(screenCopy));
    JScrollPane screenScroll = new JScrollPane(screenLabel);

    screenScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(
            (int)(im.getWidth(null)),
            (int)(im.getHeight(null))));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(screenScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    final JLabel selectionLabel = new JLabel(
            "Drag a rectangle in the screen shot!");
    panel.add(selectionLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    repaint(screenCopy1, screenCopy);
    screenLabel.repaint();

    screenLabel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

        Point start = new Point();

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
            start = me.getPoint();
            repaint(screenCopy1, screenCopy);
            selectionLabel.setText("Start Point: " + start);
            screenLabel.repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
            Point end = me.getPoint();
            captureRect = new Rectangle(start,
                    new Dimension(end.x-start.x, end.y-start.y));
            repaint(screenCopy1, screenCopy);
            screenLabel.repaint();
            selectionLabel.setText("Rectangle: " + captureRect);
        }
    });

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);

    System.out.println("Rectangle of interest: " + captureRect);
}  


public void repaint(BufferedImage orig, BufferedImage copy) {
    Graphics2D g = copy.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(orig,0,0, null);
    if (captureRect!=null) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.draw(captureRect);
        g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255,150));
        g.fill(captureRect);
    }
    g.dispose();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                new ScreenCaptureRectangle(ImageIO.read(new File("Desert.jpg")));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: For the future, you should try to limit your code to only show the problem at hand. Most people will be put off by having to read through  heaps of Swing code that has nothing to do with the issue. A side effect of this practice is, in many cases, you will find the problem yourself.

Comment: Sure, i'll keep that in mind. Can you help me with one more thing. I need to open, display image and capture coordinates on webpage based on user selection just like this app is doing. Any idea where to start?

Comment: I suggest googling and reading up on the issue. There's a number of HTML/JS frameworks out there that might help. If you don't find anything, try asking a new question on SO. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you never paint the original image (`im`, read from `"Desert.jpg"`) into any of your `screenCopy` or `screenCopy1` images, you only create empty `BufferedImage`s of the same size. These "copies" will always stay blank.

Comment: Oops, that was so silly of me. Probably overburdened by work :P. Thanks a lot for your help. Problem solved :)